# How to do login into Before annotated method using Graphene?

Tags: java, selenium, jboss-arquillian, graphene2

I'm learning Graphene and created to page objects for a login page and a welcome page.

Loginpage

```
@Location("myurl/login.xhtml")
public class LoginPage {

  @Drone
  private WebDriver driver;

  @FindBy(id = "username")
  private WebElement txtUserName;

  @FindBy(id = "password")
  private WebElement txtPassword;

  @FindBy(id = "loginbutton")
  private WebElement btnLogin;

  public WebElement txtUserName() {
    return txtUserName;
  }

  public WebElement getTxtPassword() {
    return txtPassword;
  }

  public WebElement getBtnLogin() {
    return btnLogin;
  }

  public void login(String username, String password) {
    this.txtUserName().clear();
    this.getTxtPassword().clear();
    this.txtUserName().sendKeys(username);
    this.getTxtPassword().sendKeys(password);

    // Submit form and get redirect to welcome page
    Graphene.guardHttp(this.getBtnLogin()).click();
  }
}
```

Welcome Page:

```
@Location("myurl/")
public class WelcomePage {

  @Drone
  private WebDriver driver;

  @FindBy(tagName = "nav")
  NavigationFragment navigation;

  @FindBy(id = "version")
  WebElement labelVersion;

  public WebElement getLabelVersion() {
    return labelVersion;
  }

  public NavigationFragment getNavigation() {
    return navigation;
  }

}
```

As you can see my page objects using the `@Location` annotation. I then created two test classes, one for each page:

Test of login page. Try to login and check element of following (welcome) page.

```
public class LoginpageTest {

  @Drone
  protected WebDriver browser;

  @ArquillianResource
  protected URL baseUrl;

  @Test
  public void testLogin(@InitialPage LoginPage page) {

    // Login into page
    page.login("username", "password");

    // Check version label is showing correct version
    WebElement versionLabel = browser.findElement(By.id("version"));
    Assert.assertEquals("Wrong version", "Version 0.2.4", versionLabel.getText());
  }

}
```

Test welcome page.

```
public class WelcomepageTest {

  @Drone
  protected WebDriver browser;

  @ArquillianResource
  protected URL baseUrl;

  @Page
  private WelcomePage page;

  @Test
  public void testVersion(@InitialPage LoginPage loginpage) {

      // Login into page
      loginpage.login("username", "password");  

      // Check version label is showing correct version
      Assert.assertEquals("Versionslabel falsch", "Version 0.2.4", page.getLabelVersion().getText());

  }

  @Test
  public void testSomethingElse(@InitialPage LoginPage loginpage) {

      // Login into page
      loginpage.login("username", "password");  

      // Check something else

  }      
}
```

This works, but I would like to extract the redudant login from the testcase, so that I only got one place where it's needs to be maintained. All tutorials and wiki articles I read in the past few hours always do the login over and over again in each test method. As I would like to avoid that, I tried to extract it into a `@Before` method like this:

```
public class BeforeWelcomepageTest {

  @Drone
  protected WebDriver browser;

  @ArquillianResource
  protected URL baseUrl;

  @Page
  private WelcomePage page;

  @Before
  public void login(@InitialPage LoginPage loginpage) {
    // Load loginpage via @InitialPage and do login
    loginpage.login("username", "password");
  }      

  @Test
  public void testVersion() { 
    // Login should be done via @Before - method

    // Check version label is showing correct version
    Assert.assertEquals("Versionslabel falsch", "Version 0.2.4", page.getLabelVersion().getText());
  }

}
```

But this gives me the following `IllegalArgumentException` exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

So I think a method annotated with `@Before` must not contain any arguments.

I then tried to write a `@Before`-method to manually open the login page, similar to suggestions in several (older) selenium questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053170/initialize-page-objects-arquillian-selenium/43081432#43081432). So I created the following class but struggled on opening the url of my login page, login and "land" on my welcome page.

```
public class SecondBeforeWelcomepageTest {

  @Drone
  protected WebDriver browser;

  @ArquillianResource
  protected URL baseUrl;

  @Page
  private LoginPage loginpage;

  @Page
  private WelcomePage page;

  @Before
  public void login() {
    // Load loginpage via browser
    browser.get(baseURL + "myurl/");

    // Same with
    // Graphene.goTo(LoginPage.class)

    // do login
    loginpage.login("username", "password");
  }      

  @Test
  public void testVersion() { 
    // Login should be done via @Before - method

    // Check version label is showing correct version
    Assert.assertEquals("Versionslabel falsch", "Version 0.2.4", page.getLabelVersion().getText());
  }

}
```

But this brings two problems: First the URL of my page object is hard coded in the test (maybe [using reflection API like in this question] is a workaround. Second problem is: It does not work as the `WelcomePage` page is not opened and therefore the version label isn't found.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: label

Does anyone knows a solution for extract the login into a non redunant method, executed before each `@Test` and provide valid objects?

Comment: What do you mean by WelcomePage is not opened? The user should land on the welcomepage by the application if the login is successful, rt?

Comment: @vins Yes. After the login the user is redirected to the welcome page, but this doesn't work when I try it like in `SecondBeforeWelcomepageTest`

Comment: you still have this issue? Can you please upload this project somewhere to replicate?

Comment: I still have the issue and I can't upload it somewhere as it's internal project of my company.